# In Skype my microphone doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, skype, microphone

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 500S laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 on it. When I use Skype 4.3 for Linux, my mic just doesn't work. When I open the sound setting it shows that it uses PulseAudio.

I also have SimpleScreenRecorder installed on my system. My mic works fine here and the video has my sound from my mic. But in SimpleScreenRecorder I can change PuseAudio to ALSA.

Is there anyway I can use ALSA on Skype? Or does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Did you try to use new Skype? https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299

Comment: @LjiljanVeselinovic already try it.. but no luck.. :(